# Feed JSON data into HTML form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, forms

I have some JSON:

```
"accessories":{
  "tableware01":{
     "sku":"tableware01",
     "forceAmountHidden":"1",
     "upsell":"1",
     "discountAll":"1",
     "forceRemove":"1",
     "percentageDiscount":"12",
     "fixedDiscount":"1",
     "forceAmount":"1",
     "maximumQuantity":"12",
     "endDate":"2014-12-12T00:00:00",
     "minimumQuantity":"1",
     "startDate":"2012-12-12T00:00:00"
  },
  "cla000":{
     "sku":"cla000",
     "forceAmountHidden":"1",
     "upsell":"1",
     "discountAll":"1",
     "forceRemove":"1",
     "percentageDiscount":"23",
     "fixedDiscount":"1",
     "forceAmount":"1",
     "maximumQuantity":"123",
     "endDate":"2015-02-03T00:00:00",
     "minimumQuantity":"1",
     "startDate":"2011-02-03T00:00:00"
  }
   }
```

I need to push this data into a form. The fields that I need to generate must look like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="accsku1">
<input type="hidden" name="accdisc1">
<input type="hidden" name="accperc1">
<input type="hidden" name="accreg1">
<input type="hidden" name="accupsell1">
<input type="hidden" name="accnum">
<input type="hidden" name="acclimit1">
<input type="hidden" name="accforce1">
<input type="hidden" name="accforcehid1">
<input type="hidden" name="accforcerm1">
```

I cannot control the key in the JSON and I cannot control the name of the form field - these need to remain. I know which fields correspond to which keys in the JSON i.e. 'accdisc' is 'fixedDiscount'. I need to insert the correct value from the JSON into the value of the field. Also, the fields iterate (starting from 1) according to the number of accessories there are i.e. my form will continue with

```
<input type="hidden" name="accsku2">
<input type="hidden" name="accdisc2">
```

and so on.

I'm quite new to working with JSON but I've been getting through this project ok up to this point where I'm just not sure how to approach this. I would like to be able to generate the fields as I will not know how many accessories I'll have. I was wondering if I could create some sort of map where I can say 'sku matches input accsku' then add an index?

The JSON is a snippet of a larger file containing a lot of product data with varying keys, this is an example of how I am pulling it into my form:

```
$.getJSON("urltoJSONhere",function(product){
    $.each(product.extendedFields, function(i){
        $( "<input type='hidden' name='"+this.name+"' value='"+this.data+"'>" ).appendTo( form );
    });
```

Above is much simpler for 'extendedFields' as I can use keys 'name' and 'data' to generate the input fields, but I really don't know how to approach my problem above with 'accessories'.

Can anyone give me some advice on how I might approach this please?

Additional info for clarification:

I know this:
    sku = accsku,
    fixedDiscount = accdisc,
    percentageDiscount = accperc,
    discountAll = accreg,
    upsell = accupsell,
    minimumQuantity = accnum,
    maximumQuantity = acclimit,
    forceAmount = accforce,
    forceAmountHidden = accforcehid,
    forceRemove = accforcerm

I need this in my form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="accsku1" value="tableware01">
<input type="hidden" name="accdisc1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="accperc1" value="12">
<input type="hidden" name="accreg1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="accupsell1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="accnum1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="acclimit1" value="12">
<input type="hidden" name="accforce1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="accforcehid1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="accforcerm1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="accsku2" value="cla000">
<input type="hidden" name="accdisc2" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="accperc2" value="23">
<input type="hidden" name="accreg2" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="accupsell2" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="accnum2" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="acclimit2" value="123">
<input type="hidden" name="accforce2" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="accforcehid2" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="accforcerm2" value="1">
```

Comment: Is ur json well formed. If not please post

Comment: According to JSONLint its valid. Here's the whole thing if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/hayleyeaston/u5TjH/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had some help from a work colleague who gave me some assistance creating a map which is then used to build the input fields. I'm posting this in case anyone else needs a similar solution. The script works with a form with id 'accform'.

```
var accessories = {
"tableware01": {
    "sku": "tableware01",
        "forceAmountHidden": "1",
        "upsell": "1",
        "discountAll": "1",
        "forceRemove": "1",
        "percentageDiscount": "12",
        "fixedDiscount": "1",
        "forceAmount": "1",
        "maximumQuantity": "12",
        "endDate": "2014-12-12T00:00:00",
        "minimumQuantity": "1",
        "startDate": "2012-12-12T00:00:00"
},
    "cla000": {
    "sku": "cla000",
        "forceAmountHidden": "1",
        "upsell": "1",
        "discountAll": "1",
        "forceRemove": "1",
        "percentageDiscount": "23",
        "fixedDiscount": "1",
        "forceAmount": "1",
        "maximumQuantity": "123",
        "endDate": "2015-02-03T00:00:00",
        "minimumQuantity": "1",
        "startDate": "2011-02-03T00:00:00"
}
}

var map = {
    sku: "accsku",
    forceAmountHidden: "accforcehid",
    upsell: "accupsell",
    discountAll: "accreg",
    forceRemove: "accforcerm",
    percentageDiscount: "accperc",
    fixedDiscount: "accdisc",
    forceAmount: "accforce",
    maximumQuantity: "acclimit",
    minimumQuantity: "accnum",
    endDate:"endDate",
    startDate:"startDate"
}
var form = $("#accform");
var index = 1;
for (var k in accessories) {
    var accessory = accessories[k];
    for (var prop in accessory) {
        var name = map[prop] + index;
        $('input[name=' + name + ']').val(name);
        $( "<input type='text' name='"+name+"' value='"+accessory[prop]+"'>" ).appendTo( form );
    }
    index++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link if it helps.

You need to use nested `.each` to access inner data.

http://jsfiddle.net/pE6yE/9/

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain my issue well enough. I don't have a problem accessing the data, I need to use the data to generate some form fields - shown above. For each object under accessories I need to use the key/value pair to generate a form field. I can easily print:
<input name="sku" value="tableware01">
but my form does not recognise name="sku" - it needs to be called name="accsku1".
So my problem is how can I generate a field like this given I know what key matches what name:
<input name="accsku1" value="tableware01">

Comment: Dont know whether i have got ur requirement but check if this helps http://jsfiddle.net/pE6yE/20/

Comment: We're getting there but I need to use a very specific name in the input field which is not in the JSON. Please can you see my edit in the original post.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pE6yE/29/ check this added one more .each to access key and value

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not quite it, I can see the id is generated using the prefix 'acc' and the first 3 characters of the key. I must use very specific names (in your example id) in the form fields. I cann't generate using the pattern you've used. There is no link between the key in the JSON and the name that I need. I must generate exactly the fields that are shown in my additional info above. Many thanks for your help, but I need to be able to map a totally different name to each key/value pair.

Comment: then you have to use if else case in .each or switch case to assign specific name